# What is difference between getOrderId and getLastRealOrder() function in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, orders

As I'm new to magento 2 I can't anble to trigger out the difference between getOrderId and getLastRealOrder function ?

How to get product id using **getLastRealOrder**() function?

Answer (score 0):

**getOrderId()** will give Order Id and **getLastRealOrder()** wil give that last placed order data object

Answer (score 0):

Actually `getLastRealOrder()` loads order by using last `increment id` for the session, which is unique id but not primary key of any `sales_order_*` tables. As you may see the implementation.

```
public function getLastRealOrder()
 {
    $orderId = $this->getLastRealOrderId();
    if ($this->_order !== null && $orderId == $this->_order->getIncrementId()) {
        return $this->_order;
    }
    $this->_order = $this->_orderFactory->create();
    if ($orderId) {
        $this->_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    }
    return $this->_order;
}
```

Whereas `getOrderId()` function is used to get order id of the particular order in various contexts.

Answer (score 0):

> getOrderId();  **//Returns order Id**
>
> getLastRealOrder(); **//Get order instance based on last order ID**

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, the `getOrderId()` function and the `getLastRealOrder()` function are used to retrieve order information, but they work slightly differently.

The `getOrderId()` function is a method of the `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` class

, and it is used to retrieve the **order ID** of the last order that was placed. The method retrieves the order ID from the session data and returns it as an integer.
For example, you could use the `getOrderId()` method to retrieve the order ID of the last order placed by a customer, and then use that ID to load the order object and display order details to the customer.

```
$orderId = $this->checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
$order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderId);
```

On the other hand, the `getLastRealOrder()` function is a method of the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` class and it is used to retrieve the last real order object that was placed by the customer. This method returns an instance of the `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` class, which contains all of the information about the order, including the order items, billing and shipping addresses, and order totals.

```
$order = $this->_order->load($this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId());
```

So in short, the main difference between these two functions is that `getOrderId()` retrieves the order ID as integer and `getLastRealOrder()` retrieves the complete order object, which you can use to access various data about the order.